# data patch changes does not affect database

Tags: magento2, product, database, product-collection

I have created Data Patch, debugged it and everything works as expected, products are removed from the collection but after running setup upgrade changes are not made in the database, what can be cause of the error ? **My code is below**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace DevAll\ExtensionSettingConfig\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepositoryIn;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Area;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;
class RemoveLGManufacturer implements DataPatchInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    private $attributeRepository;

    private $_productRepositoryInterface;

    private $collectionFactory;

    private $state;

    private  $productCollectionFactory;

    private $productRepository;

    private $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    public function __construct(
        State $state,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        AttributeRepositoryInterface $attributeRepository,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepositoryInterface,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->state = $state;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->_productRepositoryInterface = $productRepositoryInterface;
        $this->attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
    public function apply()
    {
          //$searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('manufacturer','LG')->create();



        $productcollection = $this->collectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer','LG')->load();
        foreach ($productcollection as $product) {
            try {
                $productcollection->removeItemByKey($product->getId());
            } catch (StateException $e) {
            }
        }
        return $productcollection;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`removeItemByKey` does not delete a product from the database. It just removes it from the product collection object.
If you want to remove products you can use

```
$this->_productRepositoryInterface->delete($product);
```

Comment: I was using that before but it returns exception message like The "1449197175" product couldn't be removed. What do you think How can I solve this problem ? Thanks for answer.

Comment: Not sure exactly what the problem might be. Try debugging. But one thing is clear. RemoveByKey does dot delete data from db

Comment: replaced it with $this->_productRepositoryInterface->delete($product);
but it returns that exception when debugging nothing more ... Yeah maybe I am stucked :D

Comment: I think it can be interesting for u .  I setted   $state->setAreaCode('frontend') ;
and It started working . thanks.